# Textinput Causes App to Crash with React native Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am making an app in react native Expo. Each time I put the focus on TextInput to enter text, the app crashes, But when i put it on the Emulator it works fine. What could possibly be wrong? Please advice.

**Edit**

Sample of the code looks thus

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
} from "react-native";
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import { Picker } from "@react-native-picker/picker";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

const VerifyPhoneNumber = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const Redirect = () => {
    navigation.navigate("VerifyNumber2");
  };

  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('');
  const [telphone, setTelephone] = useState('');
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        style={{ width: 61, height: 61, top: 48, left: 177 }}
        source={require("../assets/bringer_logo-removebg-preview.png")}
      />
      <Text style={styles.hometext}>Verify your Phone Number</Text>
      <Text style={styles.hometext2}>
        Bringer will need to verify your PhoneNumber
      </Text>

      <Picker
        style={styles.picker}
        selectedValue={selectedValue}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue(itemValue)}
      >
        <Picker.Item label="Nigeria" value="Nigeria" />
        <Picker.Item label="Canada" value="Canada" />
        <Picker.Item label="China" value="China" />
      </Picker>

      <TextInput
        value={telphone}
        placeholder=" Telephone Number"
        onChangeText={(text)=>setTelephone(text)}
        style={styles.input}
        maxLength={300}
      />

      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> Redirect()}>
          <View style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Next</Text>  
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
    
  );
};

export default VerifyPhoneNumber;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  },
  hometext: {
    marginTop: 80,
    textAlign: "center",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  hometext2: {
    flexShrink: 1,
    marginTop: 10,
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    textAlign: "center",
    fontWeight: 400,
  },
  button: {
    width: 282,
    height: 41,
    top: 70,
    left: 66,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#400080",
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#FFFF",
    textAlign: "center",
    top: 10,
  },
  input: {
    marginTop : 50,
    padding: 5,
    backgroundColor: "#D9D9D957",
    width: 282,
    height: 41,
    left: 66,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  picker: {
    top: 40,
    height: 41,
    left: 1,
    width: 282,
    alignSelf: "center",
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#D9D9D957",
  },
});
```

No idea why this crashes. I am using React native Expo. Could there apparently be a setting i am missing?

Comment: Please provide an code example.

Comment: @MichaelBahl pls see edits

Comment: It shouldn’t happen anything onFocus? Does it crash onChange?
Does this example work (https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/crash-onchange?platform=ios)

Ensure your expo go app is up to date.

Comment: @MichaelBahl i dont understand your question. But from what I see here, if i click, it crashes but on emulator it works fine

Comment: Did you test on android or ios device?
Do you have the latest Expo Go app insgtalled

Comment: on Android yes, ios no. On Android it crashes. If possible  i can share link of the apk with you

Comment: @MichaelBahl, yes i have latest Expo go app installed on my emulator and not on my Android

Comment: Try to replace TouchableOpacity with Pressable as TouchableOpacity is deprecated. Updated my sample, check it out and let me know if its working.

Comment: This has started happening to me on ios after upgrading expo/react-native/xcode. Any new info?